# How to make an indicator specific to a particular chart

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I have created an indicator that I wish to use like the prediction and measurements tools.  I enter an entry and stop loss price and the indicator draws profit targets on the chart.  However, after I place it on a chart, it uses these same values on all charts that I subsequently open.  Is there a way to get this to draw/plot only on the charts that I specifically place it on (have open trades in)?

```
//@version=4
study("Trade Targets", overlay=true)

ep = input(0.00, "Entry Price", type=input.float, confirm=true)
sl = input(0.00, "Stop Loss Price", type=input.float, confirm=true)

// truncate() truncates a given number to a certain number of decimals
truncate(number, decimals) =>
    factor = pow(10, decimals)
    int(number * factor) / factor
    
t1 = truncate(ep * 1.01, 2)
t2 = truncate(ep * 1.03, 2)
t3 = truncate(ep * 1.05, 2)
t4 = truncate(ep * 1.10, 2)
t5 = truncate(ep * 1.20, 2)

// make a new label once
//var label label_t1 = label.new(x=bar_index, y=t1, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
var label label_t2 = label.new(x=bar_index, y=t2, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
var label label_t3 = label.new(x=bar_index, y=t3, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
var label label_t4 = label.new(x=bar_index, y=t4, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)
var label label_t5 = label.new(x=bar_index, y=t5, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_none, size=size.normal, textalign=text.align_center)

if (barstate.islast) and (ep > 0.00)
    line_sl = line.new(x1=bar_index[0], y1=sl, x2=bar_index[1], y2=sl, extend=extend.left)
    //line_t1 = line.new(x1=bar_index[0], y1=t1, x2=bar_index[1], y2=t1, extend=extend.left)
    line_t2 = line.new(x1=bar_index[0], y1=t2, x2=bar_index[1], y2=t2, extend=extend.left)
    line_t3 = line.new(x1=bar_index[0], y1=t3, x2=bar_index[1], y2=t3, extend=extend.left)
    line_t4 = line.new(x1=bar_index[0], y1=t4, x2=bar_index[1], y2=t4, extend=extend.left)
    line_t5 = line.new(x1=bar_index[0], y1=t5, x2=bar_index[1], y2=t5, extend=extend.left)
    
    // Set the label content
    //label.set_text(id=label_t1, text="1% " + tostring(t1))
    label.set_text(id=label_t2, text="3% " + tostring(t2))
    label.set_text(id=label_t3, text="5% " + tostring(t3))
    label.set_text(id=label_t4, text="10% " + tostring(t4))
    label.set_text(id=label_t5, text="20% " + tostring(t5))

    // Update the label's location
    //label.set_xy(id=label_t1, x=bar_index[4], y=t1)
    label.set_xy(id=label_t2, x=bar_index[4], y=t2)
    label.set_xy(id=label_t3, x=bar_index[4], y=t3)
    label.set_xy(id=label_t4, x=bar_index[4], y=t4)
    label.set_xy(id=label_t5, x=bar_index[4], y=t5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your script depends on raw prices to be entered in its "Settings/Inputs", your script will always be symbol-specific. The concept of allowing separate instances of a script to be created for each new symbol you run it on does not exist on TV. As you have discovered, the same Inputs are used for all charts the script is run on.